# Italicized Thai diacritic misplaced by XeLaTex

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, polyglossia

In the example below, the diacritic (looking like an exclamation mark without the dot) should hover above the vowel (which in turn hovers above the consonant) as in the normal, but is instead dropped to the same level as the latter in the italics. The commented-out line does not help.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{thai}
% \newfontfamily{\thaifont}[Script=Thai]{FreeSerif}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}
Hi \emph{Hi}

\begin{thai}
กิ่ง \emph{กิ่ง}

ที่ \emph{ที่}
\end{thai}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** This problem occurs when compiling with **XeLaTex** and not LuaLaTex, as Marcel Krüger said below. Below is the expected result produced by the latter.

[image]

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Thanks for telling me that. I should have been conscious of it since I was using LuaLaTex without this problem before switching to XeLaTex. Unfortunately, the switch was necessitate by LuaLaTex's deficiency in Thai word segmentation.

Comment: I'd say this is an XY-problem. What problems have you encountered with the Thai line breaking in LuaTeX?? See for example https://github.com/latex3/babel/blob/master/samples/lua-thai.pdf . @bongbang

Comment: Wow! Thank you. That example made me realize that the deficiency I was talking about was actually my own, not LuaLaTex's. Everything works fine now and I don't need to switch anymore. For some reason, Lua gets a bad rap vs Xe when it comes to handling Thai, which led me to my faulty conclusion. See this [comment](https://twitter.com/sorawee_p/status/1341441124653703168) from someone who actually *wants* to use the former. Thanks for doing your part to correct that misimpression.

Comment: @JavierBezos The comment above is addressed to you.